# How do I access the individual indexes of a list of named tuples within a defaultdict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, defaultdict, namedtuple

I have created a defaultdict using a csv file. The defaultdict has a movie director as the key and a list of named tuples as the values. The named tuples have 3 elements: title, year and score. I need to isolate the year element, check whether the year is after a given year then check those results score element for each tuple is high than a given score.

Here is the output from the dictionary:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'James Cameron': [Movie(title='Avatar', year=2009, score=7.9), Movie(title='Titanic', year=1997, score=7.7), Movie(title='Terminator 2: Judgment Day', year=1991, score=8.5), Movie(title='True Lies', year=1994, score=7.2), Movie(title='The Abyss', year=1989, score=7.6), Movie(title='Aliens', year=1986, score=8.4), Movie(title='The Terminator', year=1984, score=8.1)]
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? You can access the values of a namedtuple by name or index, per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Comment: If I wanted to find the score for every movie, what would the code look like?

Comment: Which part of that *exactly* are you stuck on? SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service, provide a [mcve] to illustrate the specific issue with your current code.

Comment: I’ve read the docs and tried too many things to list here, I just need to access each score element in the named tuple and I am unsure how to go about this.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if i understood correctly but maybe something like like below : 
Generate a defautdict and then access the score element

```
d = defaultdict(list)
ls1 = [('James Cameron' , Movie(title='Avatar', year=2009, score=7.9)),('James Cameron' , Movie(title='avs', year=2010, score=8.1))]
for k,v in ls1:
    d[k].append(v)
for item in d['James Cameron']:
    print(item.score))
```